# PHP and ORACLE DATABASE login

Tags: php, database, oracle, authentication

Good Morning
I'm trying to login with php and an Oracle database.

The connection works fine, but the login does not work.

Does anyone know that I have bad?

Thank you very much

```
<?php
    //abrimos sesión
    session_start();

    //CAPTURO LOS INPUTS
    $user=$_POST["username"];
    $passw=$_POST["password"];

    //CONECTAMOS CON LA BBDD
    $conn = oci_connect('usuario', 'passwd', '192.168.4.88/XE');
    if (!$conn) {
        $e = oci_error();
        trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
    }else{
        echo"conexion realizada";
    }


    $resultado = oci_parse($conn, "SELECT * FROM usuarios WHERE nombre='$user' and passwd='$passw'");
    oci_execute($resultado);
    $row = oci_fetch_all($resultado);


    if($row >0){
        $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
        $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
        $_SESSION['start'] = time();
        $_SESSION['expire'] = $_SESSION['start'] + (10 * 60);
        header('location:usuario.php');
        exit;

    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('Usuario y/o Contraseña incorrectas.');
        window.location='index.html'</script>";
        session_destroy();
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: What **exactly** is the problem? Is there any error message? If not, why don't you write more conditions to check for errors in your code?

Comment: The php does not give any error, it leaves incorrect username or password

Comment: your `if($row >0){` part is wrong

Comment: Your code does not give any errors because you don't check for them. For example, your code is pretty vulnerable to SQL injections, but you don't check whether a database error occured after querying for user data

Comment: Your call to `oci_fetch_all()` should have 2 parameters (http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-all.php)

Answer (score -1):

```
$row = oci_fetch_all($conn, $resultado);
```

EDIT: Using this built-in function you have to parse connection variable. Reason for that, is that you could have multiple connections to multiple different databases in one script and so that oci_fetch_all knows from where to pull the data.

Comment: Although this might answer the question, some context could be useful for the OP...

Comment: The two required parameters for `oci_fetch_all` are the statement (not the connection), (so `$resultado`) and a variable to contain the output.

Comment: @timclutton Can you have oci_fetch_all without previously parsing query and executing it ? No. What does parsing function take? Connection string.

Comment: @MarioJurić I think you're trying to tell me my previous comment is incorrect and your answer is correct. Read the [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.oci-fetch-all.php).

Comment: $resultado in his case would be a variable containing the parsed and executed query. He has no output variable. Yes, I was wrong, it should be oci_fetch_all($resultado, $output). I apologize. He still needs an output variable tho and I think we've helped him. I barely ever use these functions because I'm working with CodeIgniter which has support for Oracle so I make mistakes when dealing with generic functions.
I also suggest using bind variables and protection this code against SQL injection since it is vulnerable